# Which of these is the the "more valid" reason of discontinuity?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

I am helping somebody with some basic calculus and I came across a question I'm not sure about. I have a graph of $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \to 3^{+}}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 3^{-}}f(x)$ both exist, but they are not equal to each other. $f(3)$ exists and is equal to $\lim_{x \to 3^{-}} f(x)$

Now the questions asks whether the function is continuous at $x=3$. The two choices it comes down to are

$A)$ No, because $\lim_{x \to3} f(x) \not =f(3)$

$B)$ No, because $\lim_{x\to 3} f(x)$ does not exist.

I'm not sure which one I should pick. I would go with the first one because it's the definition of continuity, but I have a feeling it might get marked wrong because "we can't have an undefined value in an equation" or some reason of that sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should clarify two things here,namely that continuity happens (at a point, for a function, in a domain etc.) if :

i) The limit exists, which means by definition that **both** the **right** and **left** hand limit exist, and are **equal to each other**.

ii) **Given that the above is true**, the limit in (i) (doesn't matter if it's left or right, since they're both the same) is the same as the function value at the point.

The point is, you have to verify the conditions above in a given order, namely you first check for i), then for ii). If you do that, you will realize that the answer to your question is B.

Answer (score 4):

Choice B is better because choice A is making a statement about something which does not exist.